# How to distribute evenly & automatically items of an horizontal list in a container w/css ala apple

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox, navbar

I'd like to create a large navbar similar to apple.com's.

What I try to reproduce from apple's navbar is :

- the li in the navbar are centered;
- the browser automatically distribute evenly the space between each li  in the ul container
  (different from flex-grow as explained here:
  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/);
- only the space between the li elements is resized when resizing the
  browser's window.

html:

```
<nav id="gn">
  <div id="gn-content">
    <ul class="gn-menu">
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-brand"><a class="gn-link gn-link-brand" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Brand</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-products"><a class="gn-link gn-link-products" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Products</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-services"><a class="gn-link gn-link-services" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Services</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-about"><a class="gn-link gn-link-about" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">About</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-contact"><a class="gn-link gn-link-contact" href="www.soundbody.io/contact"><span class="gn-link-span">Contact</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-signin"><a class="gn-link gn-link-signin" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Sign In</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#gn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #212121;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gn #gn-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 22px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  z-index: 2;
}

#gn .gn-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  z-index: 3;
}

#gn .gn-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 4;
}

#gn .gn-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-origin: content-box;
  z-index: 5;
}

#gn .gn-link-span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  top: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gn-link-brand {
  background-image: url("/img/brand.svg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I cannot find the trick on the net. Would appreciate your help!

Cheers!

Comment: apple.com are using svg's as there text .. you can follow the same approach its very easy

Comment: Since we don't write up code to users here at SO, please post a working code snippet and we'll see if we can make it work how you want

Comment: thanks for your prompt feedback. let me edit my post as you recommended...

Answer (score 0):

Here I used `flexbox`.

You also had some none needed properties set, which I cleared out.

```css
#gn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #212121;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gn #gn-content {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 22px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

#gn .gn-menu {
  display: flex;                   /*  added property  */

  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#gn .gn-item {
  flex: 1;                         /*  added property  */
}

#gn .gn-link {
  display: flex;                   /*  added property  */
  justify-content: center;         /*  added property  */
  align-items: center;             /*  added property  */

  height: 44px;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#gn .gn-link-span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gn-link-brand {
  background-image: url("/img/brand.svg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<nav id="gn">
  <div id="gn-content">
    <ul class="gn-menu">
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-brand"><a class="gn-link gn-link-brand" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Brand</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-products"><a class="gn-link gn-link-products" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Products</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-services"><a class="gn-link gn-link-services" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Services</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-about"><a class="gn-link gn-link-about" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">About</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-contact"><a class="gn-link gn-link-contact" href="www.soundbody.io/contact"><span class="gn-link-span">Contact</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-signin"><a class="gn-link gn-link-signin" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Sign In</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Updated based on a comment, using `justify-content: space-around;` instead `flex: 1` for the items

```css
#gn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #212121;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gn #gn-content {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 22px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

#gn .gn-menu {
  display: flex;                   /*  added property  */
  justify-content: space-around;   /*  added property  */
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#gn .gn-link {
  display: flex;                   /*  added property  */
  justify-content: center;         /*  added property  */
  align-items: center;             /*  added property  */

  height: 44px;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#gn .gn-link-span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gn-link-brand {
  background-image: url("/img/brand.svg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<nav id="gn">
  <div id="gn-content">
    <ul class="gn-menu">
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-brand"><a class="gn-link gn-link-brand" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Brand</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-products"><a class="gn-link gn-link-products" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Products</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-services"><a class="gn-link gn-link-services" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Services</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-about"><a class="gn-link gn-link-about" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">About</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-contact"><a class="gn-link gn-link-contact" href="www.soundbody.io/contact"><span class="gn-link-span">Contact</span></a></li>
      <li class="gn-item gn-menu-signin"><a class="gn-link gn-link-signin" href="#"><span class="gn-link-span">Sign In</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi LGSon, tx for the quick help! The issue I have with  this solution is that there are no gaps / non clickable areas between links. The nice touch from Apple is there are blanks/non-clickable area between links. I've not been able to fix that using the flex property...

Comment: @ElGringotte Will update my answer fixing that, notify you when done

Comment: @ElGringotte Updated my answer

Comment: It WORKS!!! I suck w/ flex property. I'll get better over the weekend! Have a great weekend yourself!

Comment: @ElGringotte As my answer worked, it would be great if you could accept it as well